# knife cookbook site downland with all dependencies

Tags: chef, knife, cookbook

I'm just starting out with chef, and I'm following http://gettingstartedwithchef.com. One thing it suggests is using `knife cookbook site download $COOKBOOK_NAME` to get community cookbooks. However sometimes they come with dependencies, and I then have to wait untill Vagrant tells me there's a problem and then manually download and install the packages one by one.

Is there anyway to get knife to download all the dependencies that a cookbook needs? It would speed things up.

I noticed `knife cookbook site install`, but that wants to do a pile of git stuff, which I don't want to do. I want to download the cookbook (which also means dependencies), I don't want to be making commits.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Berkshelf or Librarian to manage your cookbooks.  It is MUCH easier than doing it with knife, and handles dependencies for you.